# underscore.js removing text from string based on array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Having a little issue with some logic and underscore.js.

I have the following array of common words:

```
var common_words = ["a", "an", "the", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "can", "did", "do", "does", "for", "from", "had", "has", "have", "here", "how", "i", "if","in", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "so", "that", "the", "then", "there", "this", "to", "too", "up", "use", "what", "when", "where", "who", "why", "you"];
```

and I have the following string being passed in:

```
this is the printer that has the words on it
```

now what should happen is that all the common words should get stripped out simply leaving the words "printer" and "words".

I have tried using underscore.js as below but it is not working as expected and simply returning everything that matches the common_words array.

```
$('.tagTrigger').blur(function () {
        var subjectVal = $('#txtSubject').val().split(/ +/);

        $.each(subjectVal, function (index, itm) {
            console.log(itm);
            console.log(_.reject(common_words, function (item) { return item != itm }));
        });
    });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, just need another pair of eyes I guess :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> now what should happen is that all the common words should get
>   stripped out simply leaving the words "printer" and "words".

I don't think you need underscorejs here. The following would suffice.

```
var subjectVal = "this is the printer that has the words on it";
subjectVal = subjectVal.replace(new RegExp("\\b(" + common_words.join("|") + ")\\b", "g"), "");
```

The above would leave the words but with spaces, which can be easily removed like

```
var result = subjectVal.replace(/\s+/g," ").trim();
```

Comment: Yes that change is necessary I think, but also I think you need to add parentheses around the words - "\\b(" + ... + ")\\b" right?

Comment: Did not think to try this and indeed it works but.... this is what gets returned: "s  prnter    wds  t"  I guess what is happening here is that single letters such as "i" and "a" are being stripped out from the non common words.

Comment: It is question of underscore.js, not of angularjs

Comment: @OPSoftware check out my current code.. It shouldn't happen

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need Underscore. You can use pure Javascript by splitting your sentence and filtering it with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
"this is the printer that has the words on it".split(" ").filter(function(word){
    return common_words.indexOf(word) === -1;
}).join(' ');
```

results

```
"printer words"
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here's a version using underscore:

```
var commonWord = function(word){
   return _.contains(common_words, word);
}

var text = "this is the printer that has the words on it";
var words = text.split(' ');

var uncommonWords = _.reject(words, commonWord);
```

```js
var common_words = ["a", "an", "the", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "can", "did", "do", "does", "for", "from", "had", "has", "have", "here", "how", "i", "if","in", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "so", "that", "the", "then", "there", "this", "to", "too", "up", "use", "what", "when", "where", "who", "why", "you"];

var commonWord = function(word){
  return _.contains(common_words, word);
}

var text = "this is the printer that has the words on it";
var words = text.split(' ');

var uncommonWords = _.reject(words, commonWord);

document.getElementById("uncommonText").innerHTML = uncommonWords.join(' ')
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p id='uncommonText'></p>
```

Comment: I actually ended up using this one as we already have underscore.js in the project and this seem to be a cleaner and faster solution.  I had implemented @AmitJoki answer and it worked great but as he was the one that came up with the solution first I have left the accepted answer with him.